# How to execute rgbdslam offline

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rosbag, offline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am very new to ROS and would like to ask how to execute RGBDSLAM offline to already recorded bag files with image and depth topics from the kinect ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10678/how-to-execute-rgbdslam-offline/) by [vio](https://answers.ros.org/users/868/vio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/980/what-topics-is-my-nodelet-listening-to-for-rgbd6d).

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0